# Setting status of other rows after INSERT

Tags: php, sql

Hey, I have a field called STATUS and it is either 1 to show or 0 to hide. My code is below. I am using an edit in place editor with jQuery. Everytime you update it creates a new ROW which I want, but I want only the new one to have STATUS = 1 and the others to 0. Any ideas on how I would do that?

```
<?php
    include "../../inc/config.inc.php";
    $temp  = explode("_", $_REQUEST['element_id'] );
    $field = $temp[0];
    $id    = $temp[1];
    $textboxval = stripslashes(mysql_real_escape_string(preg_replace('/[\$]/',"",$_REQUEST["update_value"])));      
    $query      = "INSERT INTO notes ($field,status,date,c_id) VALUES ('$textboxval','1',NOW(),'$id')";
    mysql_query($query);
    echo($_REQUEST['update_value']);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure exactly what you mean - do you want to make all the entries except the new one have status = 0? If so, just issue an update before the insert:

```
UPDATE notes SET status = 0
```

However, I should also note that you have a potential SQL injection to worry about. By stripping slashes *after* applying "mysql real escape string", you are potentially allowing someone to put text in your SQL statement that will execute an arbitrary SQL statement.

Comment: Thank you for that! I will go change that right away. I should reword that differently. I want to keep track on the notes sent over, so i use STATUS as 1 to only show the LATEST one.

Thanks,

Ryan

Comment: So basically, after you do the INSERT, you want to set all the rows to status = 0 (all the ones except the one you inserted)? Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: You are correct. Only show the latest one which is after the INSERT.

Thanks,

Ryan

Comment: I got it! Thank you for your help with this.

RYAn

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, sorry for the post before, I mis read it the first time then went back:

```
<?php
    include "../../inc/config.inc.php";
    $temp  = explode("_", $_REQUEST['element_id'] );
    $field = $temp[0];
    $id    = $temp[1];
    $textboxval = mysql_real_escape_stringstripslashes((preg_replace('/[\$]/',"",$_REQUEST["update_value"]))); 
    // set older entries to 0 - to not show but show in history
    $hide_notes      = "UPDATE notes SET status = 0";
    mysql_query($hide_notes);

    // add new entry with status of 1 to show only latest note
    $query      = "INSERT INTO notes ($field,status,date,c_id) VALUES ('$textboxval','1',NOW(),'$id')";
    mysql_query($query);
    echo($_REQUEST['update_value']);
?>
```

i just ran in to a problem I didn't of the set up of my table doesn't allow me to show more than one client a time and i will be having numerous clients, my bad on planning ha

Answer (score 0):

You really want to get the ID of the newly generated row and then trigger an UPDATE where you all rows where the ID is *not* the new row, e.g.

```
UPDATE notes SET status = 0 WHERE id != $newly_generated_id
```

If the ID column in your table is using AUTO_INCREMENT you can get its ID via "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()" and then use the return value in that statement in your UPDATE statement.

Pseudo code:

```
$insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO ..."); 
$last_id = mysql_query("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()"); 
$update = mysql_quqery("UPDATE notes SET status = 0 WHERE id != $last_id");
```

The only caveat to this approach is where you might have a brief moment in time where 2 rows have status=1 (the time between your INSERT and the UPDATE). I would wrap all of this in a transaction to make the whole unit more atomic.

Comment: A quick comment on this. I'm not sure he's using AUTO_INCREMENT, but if he is, this might be easier for the $last_id line:

$last_id = mysql_insert_id();